# Android Device Monitor failed to start Monitoring

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-device-monitor

I want to start Android device Monitor in android studio for Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5, and I have this trouble 
Failed to start monitoring AXS0216109001457
when I want the start Android device monitor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried to restart/reinstall everything. Finally, helped downgrading from `jdk_8u152` to `jdk8_u151`. In addition, I've added `JAVA_HOME` environmental value, maybe this fact influenced its work too.

Don't forget to remove initial version (or set downgraded one as a default), otherwise, it still won't work.